# geom_smooth() creating multiple lines, likely an aesthetics problem

Tags: r

(Tried looking for other questions, could not find a good one.)

I am trying to create a single geom_smooth() line, but I keep getting multiple. Here is my code:

```
plot1 <-
 ggplot(gapminder) +
 aes(y = lifeExp, x = gdpPercap, shape = continent, color = year) +
 labs(y = "Life Expectancy") + guides(color = "none") +
 geom_point() +
 scale_x_log10()

plot1 + geom_smooth()
```

I believe this has to do with where I put my aesthetics or how I formatted them on their own.

Any help is appreciated.

Oh, to clarify, I am getting a different line for each continent. I only want one overall line.

Thank you.

Comment: `color` and `shape` both cause this. If you want these to be global for the single line add them into `geom_smooth` outside `aes`

Comment: Move shape and colour outside the call to aes.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to move only the aesthetics of shape and color directly into `geom_point()` but leave the axes alone.

Here is the correct code:

```
plot1 <-
  ggplot(gapminder, mapping = aes(y = lifeExp, x = gdpPercap)) +
  labs(y = "Life Expectancy") +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(shape = continent, color = year)) +
  guides(color = "none") +
  scale_x_log10()

plot1 +
  geom_smooth()
```

Thank you.